# Suggestions needed: Adding fake product to cart and bring it to order

Tags: magento2, orders, addtocart

I have a request to solve a problem and I wanted to ask if somebody has already faced a similar problem and got a good suggestion on how to go about implementing it.

We sell car parts (Auto parts) for BMW and there are about 1mio parts.
I don´t want to import all parts as products in the Magento 2 database and want to add like temporary products to the shopping cart, bring it to the order and maybe afterwards delete the product so I don´t fill my database with too much data.

The customer clicks through a form where he selects his car and then gets the parts suitable for his car, where he picks one part and adds this to the cart.
So I get the required data such as SKU, price, weight and so on from that external website by requesting them.

**My Suggestions:**

> - Create a dummy product in Magento and always add this programmatically to the cart with new parts number, price, weight and
>     so on, every time a customer puts something in the cart.
> - Create a new full Magento product everytime the customer puts something in the cart and delete these newly created products after some
>     days to keep the database clean. Products in orders stay, even if the
>     products where deleted.

Does anyone have another good suggestion or experience with adding fake products in Magento 2?

Any ideas of side effects?

Comment: Why is 1million products a problem? If you have that big a catalog you should have the sales to get the computing resources to match.

Comment: We will not have a big catalog like that to sell. It´s 1 Million parts because if you for example order a fuel strainer (http://www.realoem.com/bmw/enUS/showparts?id=UK51-EUR-01-2011-E81-BMW-116d&diagId=13_1115) you´ve got one fuel strainer + 7 additional products needed for this part.
So you gonna have on main product and 7 related products. This makes about 100k normal products with extra related products.
Problem is, that we would always need to reorder the released parts and import them or use something like tecdoc which is a little too expensive for the about 200 orders per month

Comment: So do you have 100k products and 1mil parts that aren't customer facing? In other words, I wouldn't be able to order only the clamp (nr. 3 in the picture) from you?

Comment: you are able to order only the clamp. So you´re right, that´s about 1mio parts you can order. But that doesn´t mean, everybody in Germany is buying just our parts and we have that much sales to pay every extension and tecdoc API etc.