# Order "non-existant" product

Tags: magento2, addtocart, products

I have my products repository externally and only use Magento 2 to actually order these items. Similar to [this question here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223072/suggestions-needed-adding-fake-product-to-cart-and-bring-it-to-order) but unfortunaly that does not have an answer or specifics about implementation. Magento should not have access to the entire repository so I do not want to create a provider for that.

Currently I have my controller implemented to add a generic product to the cart and then differenciate them using an "sku" option.

The generic "order" object Magento is getting is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "sku": "EV4-HI-TML90180",
        "options": [...],
        "price": 213.00
    },
    {
        "sku": "ETM-SGR-2010",
        "options": [...],
        "price": 321.00
    },
]
```

I am adding this to the cart as follows:

```php
private function addItemToCart(CartItem $item)
{
    $product = $this->getProductBySku("simpleproduct");

    // Set the name and the price of the product.
    // TODO: Fix name being "Simple product" in the cart.
    $product->setName($item->getSku());
    $product->setPrice($item->getPrice());

    // Fetch the SKU option for the generic product
    $option = $this->getOptionBySku($product, 'eg-sku');
    $product->addCustomOption('option_ids', $option->getData('option_id'));
    $product->addCustomOption('option_'.$option->getData('option_id'),
        $item->getSku()); // Set the SKU option value.

    $cartItem = $this->itemFactory->create();
    $cartItem->setName($item->getSku());
    $cartItem->setCustomPrice($item->getPrice());
    $cartItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($item->getPrice());
    $cartItem->setProduct($product);

    $this->cart->getQuote()->addItem($cartItem);
}
```

But it is complaining about dividing by 0 (WTF?)

```
Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractAggregateCalculator.php on line 158
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it using an Observer that listens for products being added to the cart, and then update the item. Rather than the controller.

etc/event.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Observer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer.php

```php
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item ); // Set the parent item if item is virtual
    $price = $item->getProduct()->getPrice(); // Get the price from the product
    $item->setCustomPrice($price); // Set it over the item
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price); // Forget that it was changed, so magento wont change it back randomly
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

This still shows the name of the "generic" product in the cart, not the SKU of the  non-existant product.